# How to get http_ metrics from Spring-Boot Api

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus

I have list of metrics from Spring Boot Api but it doesn't contains http_* metrics

my pom.xml contains

```
<prometheus.version>0.1.0</prometheus.version>
      ....

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
  <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
  <version>${prometheus.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
  <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
  <version>${prometheus.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
  <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
  <version>${prometheus.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I made DefaultExports.initialize() and set bean

```
@Bean
  SpringBootMetricsCollector springBootMetricsCollector(Collection<PublicMetrics> publicMetrics) {


    SpringBootMetricsCollector springBootMetricsCollector = new SpringBootMetricsCollector(publicMetrics);
    springBootMetricsCollector.register();

    return springBootMetricsCollector;
  }
```

then i get list of metrics from spring boot api but it does not contain htpp_ * metrics
like http_request_duration_microseconds
how can i get it?

Comment: [Spring Boot 2.0](https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/spring-boot-2-0-0-m4-available-now) includes support for [Micrometer](http://micrometer.io/) metrics, which can be somehow fed directly into prometheus. Try that.